# Terraform Variables Not Being Expanded

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have a json file `bucketPolicy.json`

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::$${aws_s3_bucket.destination.id}",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["*"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And I've created a template_file as such

```
data "template_file" "test" {
  template = file("./templates/destinationBucketPolicy.json")
  vars = {
    (aws_s3_bucket.destination.id) = var.destination_bucket_name

  }
}
```

But when I try to use this for my bucket policy

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "destination" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.destination.id

  policy = data.template_file.test.rendered
}
```

The value for `var.destination_bucket_name` does not not get expanded into the policy, instead it appears literally as `"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.destination.id}"`

Is there a way to get this to expand so that it picks up the actual value for the variable?

Comment: Using a single `$` throws the error `failed to render : <template_file>:9,35-48: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "aws_s3_bucket".` which is why I tried the double `$$`. 

But then, this now doesn't do any expansion.

Comment: Don't use dots (`.`) in the name of a variable. Separating something with dots will mean that you are referencing an attribute of it. Just have something simple, like `bucket_name = var.destination_bucket_name` and use `${bucket_name}` in the template file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These days its better to use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile):

```
locals {
  test = templatefile("${path.module}/destinationBucketPolicy.json",
             {
                 bucket_name = var.destination_bucket_name
             })
}
```

with template of:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${bucket_name}",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": ["*"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. 
This makes sense and works.